# Split string on parentheses and braces

Tags: vb.net, split

Let me say, I hate working with strings! I'm trying to find a way to split a string on brackets. For example, the string is:

`Hello (this is) me!`

And, from this string, get an array with *Hello* and *me*. I would like to do this with parentheses and braces (not with brackets). Please note that the string is variable, so something like `SubString` wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance,

*FWhite*

Comment: what you want is a parser for any sort of general solution.  the code will have to contend with mismatched sets, repeat spaces and embedded parens/brace sets (`Hello, (this {is}) me!`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions (Regex), below code should exclude text inside all parenthesis and braces, also removes an exclamation mark - feel free to expand `CleanUp` method to filter out other punctuation symbols:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim re As New Regex("\(.*\)|{.*}") 'anything inside parenthesis OR braces
    Dim input As String = "Hello (this is) me and {that is} him!"
    Dim inputParsed As String = re.Replace(input, String.Empty)

    Dim reSplit As New Regex("\b") 'split by word boundary
    Dim output() As String = CleanUp(reSplit.Split(inputParsed))
    'output = {"Hello", "me", "and", "him"}
  End Sub

  Private Function CleanUp(output As String()) As String()
    Dim outputFiltered As New List(Of String)
    For Each v As String In output
      If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v) Then Continue For 'remove spaces
      If v = "!" Then Continue For 'remove punctuation, feel free to expand
      outputFiltered.Add(v)
    Next
    Return outputFiltered.ToArray
  End Function

End Module
```

To explain the regular expression I used (`\(.*\)|{.*}`):

1. `\(` is just a `(`, parenthesis is a special symbol in Regex, needs to be escaped with a `\`.
2. `.*` means anything, i.e. literally any combination of characters.
3. `|` is a logical OR, so the expression will match either left or ride side of it.
4. `{` does not need escaping, so it just goes as is.

Overall, you can read this as *Find anything inside parenthesis or braces*, then the code says replace the findings with an empty string, i.e. remove all occurrences. One of the interesting concepts here is understanding [greedy vs lazy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). In this particular case greedy (default) works well, but it's good to know other options.

Useful resources for working with Regex:

- http://regex101.com/ - Regex test/practice/sandbox.
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - Theory and examples.
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html - How word boundaries work.

Comment: Thank you Neolisk, I edited your code to split instead of replacing (I've used `RegEx.Split`). It works perfecly!

Comment: Thanks for the references too. I've never been good at RegEx! _FWhite_

Comment: How do I split brackets too? How do I edit the regex pattern to split them? Thank you so much. _FWhite_

Comment: @PWhite: Like this - `\(.*\)|{.*}|\[.*\]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    Dim var As String = "Hello ( me!"
    Dim arr() As String = var.Split("(")

    MsgBox(arr(0))      'Display Hello
    MsgBox(arr(1))      'Display me!
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Dim x As String = "Hello (this is) me"
Dim firstString As String = x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf("("))
Dim secondString As String = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(")") + 1)
Dim finalString = firstString & secondString

x = "Hello (this is) me"

firstString = "Hello "

secondString = " me"

finalString = "Hello  me"
```

Comment: actually `finalString` will be `"Hello__me"` - with 2 spaces; it may not matter to the OP, since they just care about am array of split up parts though

Comment: Good point - I actually put two spaces but SO removed one of them I guess...  Just updated the answer to show the two spaces. It could easily be fixed by adjusting the starting index or length of the string to retrieve.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. The problem is that I don't always have the same number of parentheses: I can have also `Hello (this) is (another) example`. _FWhite_

Comment: You could throw this in a loop that checks for the index of an opening parentheses. One second and I'll post an updated answer.

Comment: *you need a parser* not a simple split routine since you are skipping material based on a detected start char until a matching stop char is found. @PWhite

Comment: It is possible to use regex but you should explain better the cases for exclusion. For `Hello (this) is (another) example` you want Hello is example, for `Hello (this) {is} (another) example` ? Or do you have just parentheses and not curly braces to account for exclusion?

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your help. I want to exclude the text inside **all** parentheses. `Hello (this) {is} (another) example` should return as an array containing `Hello` and `example`. Thanks  _FWhite_